# How to create a virus signature from decompiled source

Tags: assembly, signature, decompiling, antivirus, virus

I have a problem where I have to create a virus signature for the Stoned Virus (Although this could apply to any virus/file).

Let's assume I have a copy of the compiled and decompiled program. I then proceed to identify the most important parts of the virus, that will always be present, in the code. As I understand it I now have to find the corresponding bytes in the compiled virus in order to create a byte signature for that critical part of the virus.

How do I proceed to find the corresponding bytes in the compiled source from the code that I identified in the decompiled version?

Extra:

- The code is in assembly
- Simply using a hash signature for the entire file is not an option
- Currently I only have the assembly code, but I can always compile this
- I am aware that Stoned would usually be located in the boot sector and not in a file. This is only an academic exercise and would be relevant to any virus.

EDIT:

The purpose of this is to be able to create virus signatures that can be used to scan a file system to find infected files as well as possibly infected files and variations of the virus code. For this reason I cannot simply use a hash of the entire file and I need to use specific parts of the virus. I can identify those parts but I do not know how to find the matching bytes in the machine code for the viral parts I identified.

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate for the [Reverse Engineering](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com) sister site.

Comment: What is this for? What have you tried? In its current form this question is going to get closed as being too broad, or unclear. Which is a shame because it is interesting

Comment: If it's in assembly, that it has already been compiled!

Comment: @KerrekSB Okay. So the commands eg. MOV ax,bx, XOR ax,ax (as an example) would be contained in the executable virus code? So I can just look for the hexadecimal equivalent of the identified commands?

Comment: I found what I was looking for here: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4393/how-to-create-a-virus-signature-from-decompiled-source

Answer (score 0):

I like how this question was posted the same day a certain university in South Africa released an [assignment](http://www.cs.up.ac.za/courses/COS720) for a post-grad security course regarding creating a suitable signature for the Stoned Virus that will result in correct results with as little false positives as possible ;)

Anyhow, since the submission deadline is over now, I can post what helped me.

[This article](http://stoned-vienna.com/html/index.php?page=analysis-of-stoned) helped me a lot in understanding exactly what the code in Stoned was doing. And ultimately the signature I used was the code that takes over the 13h Interrupt in the system.

I chose this signature because

- breaking this code breaks the virus
- Regular software is not supposed to take a system interrupt over, so it's unique to Stoned and quite viral.

Good luck with the exam on Monday!

Comment: The purpose of the assignment was to create a signature. The question however was not related to the signature or to stoned but rather how to test the signature. In other news... I agree that, that would be a good signature for the virus.